Xamarin C# Android Zxing QR Scanner
When i try to activate camera (await scanner.Scan()) there is Exception:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

This is my button :
private async void DodajQr(object senderr, EventArgs e)
{
var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
scanner.TopText = "Hold the camera up to the barcode\nAbout 6 inches away";
scanner.BottomText = "Wait for the barcode to automatically scan!";

//This will start scanning
ZXing.Result result = await scanner.Scan();
compId.Text = result.Text;
}

and MainActivity :
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();
LoadApplication(new App());
}


public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.PermissionsHandler.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}

Iam using Visual Studio with AndroidEmulator API34
Any ideas how to repair this code?

You're getting a null reference exception from your result object (the object that contains the scanned text).
You need to have a null reference check.
Like this:
ZXing.Result result = await scanner.Scan();
if(result != null) {
    compId.Text = result.Text;
}


but my result is always null

Have you enabled camera permission in your manifest? And have you enabled the runtime permission for the camera before running the scan?

Use this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/api/xamarin.essentials.permissions.camera?view=xamarin-essentials-android
